# Connecting C++ and Node JS

Tags: c++, node.js

I have been working on a project where I am interacting with a 3D camera(on a single machine) through its SDK written in C++. The extent of my knowledge in that language is just as good as what a basic crash course could teach. I need to provide an interface(web) which shows the camera preview from the SDK and when the capture image is clicked, I need to capture an Image using the SDK with a specified filename and path.
The approaches I thought of are:

1. Using NodeJS exec to capture images the compiled version(exe) of my program in C++. I am communicating the filepath and using json.
2. I could learn and use C++ CGI to simply control C++ SDK stuff.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use this. https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_c_addons

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the C++ CGI libraries out there but, as easy as they are to use, just calling an executable seems easier and cleaner.  I think the scanner should come with a bundled tool to drive it, doesn’t it?

Comment: I need to be able to send and receive data. That is why the executable option seems to not work. Thank You though.